# Textbook Notation: Meaning of cf.

Tags: notation

What is meant when an author gives an expression, labeled say $(3.4)$ and then immediately below writes: (cf. eq $3.2$)? i.e. what does the cf. stand for?

Not sure this is completely necessary but for instance I am currently looking at the text **Elementary Fluid Dynamics** by Acheson and a clear example of this can be found on pg $103$ where the author gives equation $(3.134)$ and then immediately below writes (cf. eqn $(3.117)$).

Comment: See equation 3.2. [Cf.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cf.): "The abbreviation cf. (short for the Latin: *confer/conferatur*, both meaning 'compare') is used in writing to refer the reader to other material to make a comparison with the topic being discussed. "

Comment: Refer to eq. 3.2

Comment: oh that's literally it - thanks!

Comment: The "i.e." you use is another one of those Latin based abbreviations ("id est"), and so is "e.g." ("exempli gratia"= for instance). It's not so long ago (just a few centuries) scholars wrote in Latin, mostly. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means look at or compare with equation (3.2). [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cf.) is where the abbreviation comes from.